# How to include different script inside k8s kind Secret.stringData

Tags: shell, kubernetes

I have a k8s cronjob which exports metrics periodically and there's k8s secret.yaml and I execute a script from it, called run.sh
Within run.sh, I would like to refer another script and I can't seem to find a right way to access this script or specify it in cronjob.yaml

cronjob.yaml

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: exporter
  labels:
    app: metrics-exporter

spec:
  schedule: "* * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: exporter
        spec:
          volumes:
            - name: db-dir
              emptyDir: { }
            - name: home-dir
              emptyDir: { }
            - name: run-sh
              secret:
                secretName: exporter-run-sh
            - name: clusters
              emptyDir: { }
          containers:
            - name: stats-exporter
              image: XXXX
              imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
              command:
                - /bin/bash
                - /home/scripts/run.sh
              resources: { }
              volumeMounts:
                - name: db-dir
                  mountPath: /.db
                - name: home-dir
                  mountPath: /home
                - name: run-sh
                  mountPath: /home/scripts
                - name: clusters
                  mountPath: /db-clusters
              terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
              terminationMessagePolicy: File
              securityContext:
                capabilities:
                  drop:
                    - ALL
                privileged: false
                runAsUser: 1000
                runAsNonRoot: true
                readOnlyRootFilesystem: false
                allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
          terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Here's how in secret.yaml, I run script run.sh and refer to another script inside /db-clusters.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: exporter-run-sh
type: Opaque
stringData:
  run.sh: |
    #!/bin/sh
    source $(dirname $0)/db-clusters/cluster1.sh
    # further work here
```

Here's the [image: directory structure]

Error Message:

```
/home/scripts/run.sh: line 57: /home/scripts/db-clusters/cluster1.sh: No such file or directory
```

Comment: According to the spec in your question; `/db-clusters`  is backed by `emptyDir`. So where is this `offerlist_backend.sh` come from? You probably need to revise your directory structure and file location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [secret yaml](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configmap-secret/managing-secret-using-config-file/),  In string data you need to mention “run-sh” as you need to include the secret in the run-sh volume mount.

Have a try by using `run-sh` in stringData as below :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: exporter-run-sh
type: Opaque
stringData:
  run-sh: |
    #!/bin/sh
    source $(dirname $0)/db-clusters/cluster1.sh
    # further work here
```